# Software for unit aware calculations?

Tags: math-software, unit-of-measure

When doing engineering calculations it is great convenience to do have software that keeps track of units.

Example when calculate something trivial as [stress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_%28mechanics%29):

$\sigma = \frac FA$

And be able to write:

$\frac {1kN}{1m*1mm}$ and get the answer in MPa

This is by nature a poll thread that i know is frowned upon on StackOverflow, is it going to be closed?

Comment: One of the top search results for "units software" is the appropriately named [GNU Units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/), which lets you say "You have: *ten furlongs per fortnight* / You want: *kilometers per hour*" and tells you "0.0059871429".

Comment: Write that as an answer, I guess F# is an answer too though I was looking for a GUI app.

Answer (score 6):

[Google](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=1+kilonewton+%2F+%281+metre+*+1+millimetre%29&oq=1+kilonewton+%2F+%281+metre+*+1+millimetre%29) Calculator does this nicely for units it knows about:

[image]

And you can't beat the price.

Comment: I up-voted but will leave the question open.

Comment: You also need to be able to put your expression on one line, or re-do a bunch of cutting and pasting every time you need to update a subexpression.

Answer (score 2):

One of the top search results for "units software" is the appropriately named [GNU Units](http://www.gnu.org/software/units/), which lets you say

```
You have: ten furlongs per fortnight
You want: kilometers per hour
```

and tells you "0.0059871429".

Comment: I feel a little silly posting an answer that's basically "I googled your question and got this", but there it is.

Comment: Can still be some use with a comprehensive list. I up-voted.

Answer (score 2):

There is SpeQ Mathematics for Windows environments. It is probably more of what your looking for.

http://www.speqmath.com/index.php?id=1

Answer (score 2):

**[insect](https://github.com/sharkdp/insect/)** has both web- and terminal-based versions. It does support parsing, handling and conversion of physical units, for example:

```
>>> 4kN / (0.8m * 2mm) -> MPa

   = 2.5MPa

>>> 2min + 30s

   = 2.5min

>>> 40000km / speedOfLight -> ms

   = 133.426ms

>>> 6Mbit/s * 1.5h -> GB

   = 4.05GB

>>> 2J·s + 3W

  Unification error:

    Cannot unify unit W (base units: kg·m²·s⁻³)
            with unit J·s (base units: kg·m²·s⁻¹)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll add [F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233243.aspx) to the list.

> Floating point and signed integer values in F# can have associated
>   units of measure, which are typically used to indicate length, volume,
>   mass, and so on. By using quantities with units, you enable the
>   compiler to verify that arithmetic relationships have the correct
>   units, which helps prevent programming errors.

Answer (score 1):

[MathCad](http://www.ptc.com/product/mathcad/) handles units in a nice way but it is too expensive for home use.

Comment: There is a limited feature no cost version now.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in [Frink](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/).

It has an interpreter that you can download as a desktop app. It also has a web interface, which lets you type

```
in  >> 1 kN / (1 m * 1 mm)
out >> MPa
```

to get

```
result >> 1 MPa
```

There is a list of [sample calculations](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/#SampleCalculations) covering a wide variety of physical applications.

Answer (score 1):

I'll throw my hat in the ring too. Maxima [1] has an add-on package `ezunits` which carries out various dimensional operations. Quantities can be symbolic (e.g. x meters per year) as well as numerical. The notation is, I hope, convenient: single left quote to indicate units, double left quote to indicate conversions. For the given example:

```
load (ezunits);
F : 1 ` kN;
A : 1 ` m * 1 ` mm;
sigma : F/A `` MPa;
  => 1 ` MPa
```

There's more to be said, but I'll let it be enough for now. Disclaimer: I wrote the ezunits package.

[1] http://maxima.sourceforge.net

Answer (score 1):

The [Squants](http://www.squants.com/) library provides units of measure for Scala, including a natural-language DSL:

```
val load1: Power = Kilowatts(12)        // returns Power(12, Kilowatts) or 12 kW
val load2: Power = Megawatts(0.023)     // Power: 0.023 MW
val sum = load1 + load2                 // Power: 35 kW - unit on left side is preserved
sum should be(Kilowatts(35))            
sum should be(Megawatts(0.035))         // comparisons automatically convert scale 

val load1 = 100 kW                  // Simple expressions don’t need dots
val load2 = 100 megaWatts
val time = 3.hours + 45.minutes     // Compound expressions may need dots
```

(Example taken from the README.)

Answer (score 1):

Frink Programming Language

Frink is a practical calculating tool and programming language designed to make physical calculations simple, to help ensure that answers come out right, and to make a tool that's really useful in the real world. It tracks units of measure (feet, meters, kilograms, watts, etc.) through all calculations, allowing you to mix units of measure transparently, and helps you easily verify that your answers make sense. It also contains a large data file of physical quantities, freeing you from having to look them up, and freeing you to make effortless calculations without getting bogged down in the mechanics.

[Homepage](https://frinklang.org/)
[Samples](https://frinklang.org/#SampleCalculations)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest finding a package for doing this in your programming language of choice, since you're going to be using that to check/automate your engineering calculations anyways.

## For R

The `units` library is one option. It looks something like this:

```
> library('units')
> m <- ud_units$m; mm <- ud_units$mm; kN <- ud_units$kN; MPa <- ud_units$MPa
> sigma <- 1*kN/(1*m * 1*mm)
> units(sigma)= MPa
> sigma
1 MPa
```

If you try an operation that mixes dimensions, it throws an error:

```
> 1*m + sigma
Error: cannot convert MPa into m
```

However, if you try an operation that mixes units of the same dimensions, it just puts the result in one of those units:

```
> 1*m + 1*mm
1.001 m
```

I haven't used the `units` library enough to vouch for its stability, but R libraries are typically very stable and well tested.

## For Python:

There are a few options available (one of the curses of a language that's popular among CS folks), but I think the `magnitude` module is the cleanest looking. It works like this:

```
>>> from magnitude import mg
>>> x= mg(1,'m')
>>> y= mg(1,'mm')
>>> F= mg(1,'kN')
>>> sigma= F/(x*y)
>>> print(sigma.ounit('MPa'))
1.0000 MPa
```

This module still has [a semi-serious bug which causes it to give very misleading output if you try to assign an invalid unit to an existing variable.](https://github.com/juanre/magnitude/issues/3) It also has the downside that you can't freely switch between the objects created my `mg()` and the usual numeric types. e.g., instead of `numpy.pi*mg(5,'m')**2` you'd have to wrap pi in `mg()` with no units as in `mg(numpy.pi)*mg(5,'m')**2`.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [SpeedCrunch](https://www.speedcrunch.org/). Is FOSS (free and opensource software) and Cross-platform (Windows + MAC + Linux).

You can calculate `25 meters + 8 foot in angstrom` and it will return the result in Ansgtroms. It's also possible to define functions.

Answer (score 0):

As free (but not open source) alternative to Mathcad with very similar user interface there is a windows software under https://smath.info .
There is a cloud version and free software download.
I use it for chemical engineering calculations at a vocational school.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best free and open source software for calculation with units is Calcpad:

https://calcpad.eu/

It is fast, simple and can export calculation notes to MS Word.

[See sample calculations with units](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZCuz.png)